# "The parameterized query expects a parameter which was not supplied" error

Tags: c#, sql, dataadapter

I am working on a code to implement an application. The error shows

> The parameterized query'@original_controllerIP nvchar(19), @IsNull_ControllerName int' expects the parameter @IsNull_ControllerName which was not supplied.

I have tried adding `Original_ControllerIPName` and all other parameters for the controller but did not work.

```cs
public virtual int Delete(string Original_ControllerIP) {
    if ((Original_ControllerIP == null)) {
        throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("Original_ControllerIP");
    }
    else {
        this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(Original_ControllerIP));
    }

    global::System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.State;

    if (((this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.State & global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                != global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
        this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.Open();
    }
    try {
        int returnValue = this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return returnValue;
    }
    finally {
        if ((previousConnectionState == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
            this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The parameters are like this:

```
this._adapter.DeleteCommand = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM [ControllersData] WHERE (([ControllerIP] = @Original_ControllerIP) AND ((@IsNull_ControllerName = 1 AND [ControllerName] IS NULL) OR ([ControllerName] = @Original_ControllerName)) AND ((@IsNull_ControllerMac = 1 AND [ControllerMac] IS NULL) OR ([ControllerMac] = @Original_ControllerMac)) AND ((@IsNull_ControllerStatus = 1 AND [ControllerStatus] IS NULL) OR ([ControllerStatus] = @Original_ControllerStatus)))";
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_ControllerIP", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ControllerIP", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_ControllerName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ControllerName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_ControllerName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ControllerName", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_ControllerMac", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ControllerMac", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_ControllerMac", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ControllerMac", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@IsNull_ControllerStatus", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ControllerStatus", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, true, null, "", "", ""));
        this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Original_ControllerStatus", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "ControllerStatus", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, false, null, "", "", ""));
```

Comment: Can you show where the DeleteCommand.Parameters are being setup?

Comment: Could it be that your query expects 2 parameter but you only set one? I'm asking because I see only one assigment for a parameter of your `DeleteCommand`

Comment: This looks like generated code (the `global::` prefix and superfluous parentheses are indicators).  The `@IsNull_ControllerName` parameter was likely added later and this code needs to be regenerated.

Comment: @sr28 just added the parameters setup in the question

Comment: As mentioned by Jonathan and madreflection, 2 parameters are expected; Original_ControllerIP and IsNull_ControllerName. Both will need to be supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is expecting 2 parameters: `original_controllerIP` and `IsNull_ControllerName`, but you are only supplying one:

```
this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(Original_ControllerIP));
```

You should provide both parameters:

```
this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(Original_ControllerIP));
this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters[1].Value = VALUE IN HERE;
```

If your query should only accept one parameter, it's possible you need to refresh / update your data adapter